# RStudio Visual editor - data.frame preview too narrow, does not resize

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to use the RStudio Visual Editor more for Quarto notebooks.

I really like it, but I there's an issue that makes it unusable: when I print a `data.frame` from a chunk, it gets printed in a very narrow rectangle that does not scale up  (as it would with the normal source editor).

This makes it unusable because often I can't see the full variable names or the full values.

[image]

I tried looking at the options (Global Options > R Markdown > Visual) but I can't find anything that changes this: **Editor content width** only changes the width of the text and code, not the chunk output.

Coercing a data.frame to tibble also doesn't fix this.

I'm using RStudio 2022.07.2 Build 576.

Comment: What about just using `View()`?

Comment: @Phil I need to be able to preview the data in the same tab as my code - useful to code interactively.

Comment: How many px you have set up in `Tools > Options > R Markdown > Visual > Editor content width (px)` ? Could you add a picture of what happens when you set it to 1000?

Comment: Could be relevant : https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8531

Comment: @Ruam Pimentel, I had already trying with that option (see my question), setting it to 1100 pixels. No difference if I set it to 1000.

Comment: Thanks @Waldi, I'll comment on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I know I answered this question before. I can't find that question or my answer in Stack Overflow, but I found the script I used to create & test the answer. I tested it because I think it was a few years ago. Everything seems to work.

This isn't a permanent solution. It will persist until you restart RStudio.

Step 1: Right-click anywhere in RStudio and select 'Inspect Element' from the dropdown to open developer tools. If you weren't aware, it's just like a browser that way.

[image]

Step 2: You need to use the console. Whether you use the console drawer (three dots) or the console tab (top of the inspector window, second from the left).

[image] [image]

The first JS function

At the cursor, you'll paste two javascript functions. I store these in an RMD, within a JS chunk. They won't do anything when you knit.

```
allOf = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ordinal]'); //find them all
if (allOf==undefined || allOf==null) {
  allOf = document.querySelector('[data-ordinal]');  // if there is only one
}

sAdd = "max-width: none;"           // create style to add

try{
  for(i = 0, n = allOf.length; i < n; i++){ //loop through them all
    styler = allOf[i].getAttribute("style");
    if (styler==undefined || styler==null) {    // if there are no HTML styles set
      styler = "";  
      console.log("No style attributes found for ", i);
    }
    if (styler!="width: 100%; max-width: 800px;") {// if this isn't a chunk output as expected
      continue;
      console.log("Attributes not changed for ", i);
    }
    allOf[i].setAttribute("style",styler+sAdd);    
    console.log("Attributes set for ", i);
}} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

The second JS function

```
allMore = document.querySelectorAll('.ace_lineWidgetContainer > div');  // first child of class
if (allMore==undefined || allMore==null) {
  allMore = document.querySelector('.ace_lineWidgetContainer > div');   // if there is only one
}

sAdd2 = "overflow: visible;"           // create style to add

try{
  for(j = 0, m = allMore.length; j < m; j++){ //loop through them all
    styler2 = allMore[j].getAttribute("style");
    if (styler2==undefined || styler2==null) {    // if there are no HTML styles set
      styler2 = "";  
      console.log("No styles were found for ", j)
    }
    allMore[j].setAttribute("style",styler2+sAdd2); // append new styles
    allMore[j].style.height = null;                 // remove the height style
    console.log("Attributes set for ", j); 
}} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

The console after entering the functions.

[image]

The inline rendered chunks before and after side by side

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant. I'll link this on the GH issue I opened for RStudio to look into this.